# EsLint misinterpreting import statements in no-unused-vars

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint

I have my `react` code as normal:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Common/Header';

// ...
header: (props) => <Header {...props} />
// ...other code
```

I just wanted to show that all the `imports` are being used, but still giving false error.

I am using `ESlint` config `no-unused-vars` rule, but unfortunately it is doing this:

```sh
E:\React\sg_app\src\containers\Todo\TodoScreen.js
  1:8   error  'React' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
  2:10  error  'View' is defined but never used                  no-unused-vars
  2:28  error  'StatusBar' is defined but never used             no-unused-vars
  5:8   error  'TodoFilter' is defined but never used            no-unused-vars
  6:8   error  'TodoListView' is defined but never used
```

My eslint config

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true,
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
  },
  "rules": {
      "semi": "warn",
      "no-unused-vars": "warn",
      "no-use-before-define": "off",
      "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["warn", {"max": 2}],
      "no-console": "warn",
      "arrow-parens": ["error", "as-needed"],
      "comma-dangle": "off",
      // "import/first": "error"
  }
};
```

How do i stop `eslint` from giving errors to the imports like `React, View` etc which are used as components, but mistakenly shown as unused?

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react

Comment: Are you able to share your `eslint` config file?

Comment: i think i am having some success using the plugin mentioned by @FunkeyFlo, but using that it is enforcing other unnecessary errors, too,

Comment: @MwamiTovi added the file

Comment: Ahh, I think I see where the issue is coming from...did you install `eslint-plugin-react`? If not, then you'll need to install that for `ESlint` to understand all this `react` jargon. If already installed, then you'll need to add this line to the eslint config file: `'plugin:react/recommended'` to the `"extends"` key. Makes sense?

Comment: look to this document  https://eslint.org/docs/4.0.0/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: i solve the previous issue already with imposing custom rules, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this for anyone's future reference
I found out the fix with suggestion of @FunkeyFlo
thanks for the suggestion
`plugin:react/recommended` this [npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react](http://npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react)  package extend is necessary in order to make eslint work in react.

```
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"  //this plugin is required to use eslint for react, otherwise we will get errors for 'React' import, as 'no-unused-vars'
  ],
```